# Colocar variável dentro de input type="date"

Tags: javascript, html

Como posso colocar essa variavel dentro de *input*

```
var data = new Date();
    var dataCurrente = new Date();
    if (data > dataCurrente) {
        alert("Data maior que atual");
    }
```

No caso o `new date()` tem que ser a data que eu colocar no `input type="date"`.

Comment: está confusa sua pergunta, *"colocar dentro de input*" significa no `value`?

Answer (score 3):

Coloquei uns `Alert's` só para você ver como vai montando a data até a apresentação final.

```js
var agora = new Date();
alert(agora);

var dia = ("0" + agora.getDate()).slice(-2);
alert("Hoje é dia: " + dia);

var mes = ("0" + (agora.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
alert("Do mês: " + mes);

var dataHoje = agora.getFullYear()+"-"+(mes)+"-"+(dia);
alert("Data formatada para o campo: " + dataHoje);

$('#campoQueVoceQuerSetarValor').val(dataHoje);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="campoQueVoceQuerSetarValor" type="date"></input>
```

Por mais que apresentação no campo será `dd/MM/yyyy`, note que a forma que vai     para lá é `yyyy/MM/dd`.